# MySQL - Update the same column twice

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column in a mysql table.
If I do it in two steps as below, is the column "col" updated twice in the disk ?

> update table SET col=3*col, col=col+2;

or is it written only once as in :

> update table SET col=3*col+2;

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
update table SET col=3*col+2;
```

this is better.
JUST FOR RECORD
where table is your tableName and not keyword

Answer (score 3):

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

> ...
>   Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.
>   ...

I *assume* the column on disk is only updated once (row written), as it has to validate all assignments / fields in an update, it wouldn't do to write one field and then find out there is a unique key violation.

Comment: I got the issue for a multi-table `UPDATE` where order mattered the way I wrote the query. Any clue about what "generally" means? Like, for single table `UPDATE`, what are the cases that lead to non-left-to-right updating?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the updates will run.